# File import callback not supported in solcjs

Tags: solidity, solcjs

Running `E:\projects\Greeter-Contract-master\contracts>solcjs --abi Greeter.sol` gives:

```
Greeter.sol:3:1: ParserError:
Source "contracts/Mortal.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "contracts/Mortal.sol";
^----------------------------^
```

**Greeter.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

import "contracts/Mortal.sol";

contract Greeter is Mortal {
    string greeting;
   constructor( string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function changeGreeting(  string memory _greeting) public {
        greeting = _greeting;
    }

    function greet() public view returns (string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

**Mortal.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.4;

contract Mortal {
    /* Define variable owner of the type address */
    address payable owner;

    /* This function is executed at initialization and sets the owner of the contract */
    constructor() public { owner = msg.sender; }

    /* Function to recover the funds on the contract */
    function kill() public {
        if (msg.sender == owner) 
            selfdestruct(owner); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Trying to deploy a contract?

Comment: @balajipachai: `solcjs --abi Greeter.sol` - compile a contract (obviously).

Comment: i wanted to create bin and abi files for the contract . im doing the application in android studio

Comment: Try deleting the Build Artifacts (.json files) and run the command again.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two different problems in `import "contracts/Mortal.sol"`:

1. For a local files, the input path name must start with `./`
2. Since your files reside under folder `contracts`, you should not add it to the relative path

**So in short, change this:**

```
import "contracts/Mortal.sol";
```

**To this:**

```
import "./Mortal.sol";
```

Comment: I tried that it didnt work

Comment: E:\projects\Greeter-Contract-master\contracts>solcjs --abi Greeter.sol
Greeter.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source "Mortal.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "./Mortal.sol";
^--------------------^

Comment: Try deleting the Build Artifacts (.json files) and run the command again.